Correct way to have several async processes in nodejs append to the same file
Is there a correct / better approach to using a file descriptor that several process running asynchronously can write to? e.g.:
const allTheAsyncJobs = []
const fileDescriptor = fs.openSync(pathToFile, 'a')

for (const thing of severalThings) {
    allTheAsyncJobs.push(myAsyncProcess(thing, fileDescriptor))
}
const results = promise.AllSettled(allTheAsyncJobs)
// ...

and then in each job:
const myAsyncProcess(thing, fileDescriptor) => {
// ...
    const changedThing = await doSomething(thing)
    fs.appendFileSync(fileDescriptor, `${changedThing}\n`, 'utf8')
// ...
}


Well you're using a Sync function so this blocks the process. Not much to worry about if you block parallel writes. But otherwise as long as you create one open fileDescriptor and multiple things writing to it will be buffered/queued and should write this in order.

@Evert ok thanks good to know. Honestly only used appendFileSync because I couldn't get fs.promises.appendFile to work with the given arguments and then forgot to come back and refactor this.

If you need actual asynchronous writes to be atomic (not the synchronous writes  you're using here), then you probably want to use a stream object and let the stream object sequence the writes properly.  You just need to make sure you don't put an asynchronous operation between two writes that are meant to be atomic and go together.
